# Visual Studio Emulator For Android - Hyper-V No Launch

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

Have been trying to launch the Visual Studio Emulator for Android for quite some time with the continued end result of an error code from the log of either `[Critical] XDE Exit Code: 16`, `[Critical] XDE Exit Code: 3` or an infinite "Preparing Virtual Machine" status. I've tried numerous troubleshooting guides and different device profiles but haven't had any success, nor in reproducing what has worked for others.

**Running Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit**

**Things I have tried:**

- Both Repairing and Reinstalling the Program
- Reinstalling Android Studio and SDK (along with the above in various orders)
- Changing Administrative Permission through `Microsoft Management Console`
- Running `XdeCleanup.exe`
- Creating an internal switch in `Hyper-V Manager` (removing in between attempts)
- All of the above by "Run as Administrator"

I have been able to create a virtual machine using the `Internal Switch`(s) I've created in `Hyper-V Manager` (albeit there is nothing to boot from) and can run Virtual Box successfully so I do not believe it is a question of my BIOS setup. I would greatly appreciate any insight you could offer or a possible solution that has worked for you with *this emulator*. Thanks for your help.

***Note that there is no instance of Visual Studio installed on this PC (the documentation suggests that it is not required).**

**Screens:**

[image: Emulator]
[image: Log]
[image: Microsoft Management Console]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a member of the Hyper-V Administrators group. Go to Control Panel and then Local Users and Groups. Add your username to the "Hyper-V Administrators" group. If no group exists, create it.

Comment: After doing this, and rebooting, my problem was solved.  The app told me to log out and in again, but that didn't solve it. Rebooting did solve it. I was using Windows 10 though not 8.1