# Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code: CouldntStartVm (10)

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to test the new Android Emulator for Visual Studio.

However, I got stuck in the same error.

```
27/08/2015 2:09:01 AM: [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
27/08/2015 2:09:01 AM: [Informational] Launching Device: 4" JellyBean (4.2) HDPI Phone
27/08/2015 2:09:01 AM: [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
27/08/2015 2:09:01 AM: [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
27/08/2015 2:09:01 AM: [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
27/08/2015 2:09:03 AM: [Informational] Launching emulator...
27/08/2015 2:09:57 AM: [Critical] Could not launch 'VS Emulator 4" JellyBean (4.2) HDPI Phone' device. Exit code 10.
27/08/2015 2:09:57 AM: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
27/08/2015 2:09:57 AM: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 4\" JellyBean (4.2) HDPI Phone" /memSize 512 /diagonalSize 5 /video "480x800" /vhd "C:\Users\tyller\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\4_JellyBean_(4.2)_HDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 4-inch JellyBean (4.2) HDPI Phone.tyller"
27/08/2015 2:09:57 AM: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: CouldntStartVm (10)
```

I review and try using the information in this two questions

[Visual Studio Emulator For Android - Hyper-V No Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750428/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-hyper-v-no-launch)

[Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3/31698124#31698124)

without success.

I try using different android versions of the sdk and the same error always.

I review the hyper-v configuration and the event errors from windows, but nothing is registered.

I tried using Windows 10 Pro X64 and Windows 8 Pro X64, both produce the same error.

I'm running this machines using VmWare workstation 11 from a Windows10 host.

Could anyone knows anything about this error?

Comment: I make it work changing the parameters in the vmx config for the virtual machine to 
    hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
    vhv.enable = "TRUE"

from this post [intern-android-emulator-not-starting-vmware-10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926199/vs-2015-intern-android-emulator-not-starting-vmware-10)
and 
disable OpenGL from [android-emulator-will-not-start-fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547546/visual-studio-android-emulator-will-not-start-fully)

Answer (score 1):

As your comment says, to run the emulator within VMWare, you need to disable OpenGL per the answer to this question: [Visual studio android emulator will not start fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547546/visual-studio-android-emulator-will-not-start-fully)